# Any way to print input and output data for each row during training in DL4J?

Tags: deeplearning4j, dl4j

The score for my model is dropping far too fast. For a huge dataset it's declining from > 5 to 0 well before the first epoch is complete.

I suspect I may have misconfigured it somehow and perhaps each batch contains the same data.

Is there any way to print out the inputs and outputs for each row during training so I can test this theory?